# Unable to find Context for getExternalFilesDir() function in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

So, I am trying to write text to a file in Android Studio. I have the following code:

```java
public void sampleFunction() {
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "sample-file.txt");
}
```

The issue is that the method getExternalFilesDir(null) cannot be resolved. After doing some research I have noted that I need to provide the Context class. Such as:

```
public void sampleFunction(Context c) {
    File file = new File(c.getExternalFilesDir(null), "equation_history.xml");
}
```

And when I called sampleFunction, I would simply pass in the current Context:

`sampleFunction(this);`

This normally would work, however, I need to call this function inside a setOnClickListener function for a Button. For example:

```
Button b_go = findViewById(R.id.b_go);
b_go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Functions.sampleFunction(this);
    }
});
```

So the return value for `this` is `android.view.View.OnClickListener` rather than `android.content.Context`.

How might I get around this? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `MyActivity.this`, where `MyActivity` is the name of the activity that contains this code. Or use `view.getContext()`, where `view` is the `onClick()` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing "this" as an argument try calling getApplicationContext() or if you are in fragment just call getActivity().

Answer (score 0):

What is often done is that a Context myContext variable is declared in the class, then onCreate, you populate it with myContext = this;  Then, in any listener or Async Task, you can use myContext.getExternalFilesDir(null)

Answer (score 0):

```
File storageDir = getActivity().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
```

Comment: Hey @xsico, welcome to StackOverflow, it would be nice to give a little bit of context and reference about your code, not just post it like that